# Circle equation using sin and cos

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm learning how to create plots with geometry nodes and math nodes but I'm confused why this isn't a circle that is created with 0,0 as the center axis.

[image: sin cos image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're offsetting the points from their original position, so you get

$$t\in[0,1]\mapsto\langle t + \cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t \rangle$$

Use the "Position" socket of the Set Position node if you want to set the position directly.